# Magento - Display shoppingcart image instead of "My Cart" in Toplinks?

Tags: php, css, magento

i am trying to display a shoppingcart image instead of the "My Cart"-Phrase. Above the shoppingcart image has just the number of items in the cart to appear.

To change the text one has to edit the mage/checkout/block/links.php and there this part:

```
public function addCartLink()
{
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
            : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
        } elseif ($count > 0) {
            $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
        } else {
            $text = $this->__('My Cart (0 items)');
        }
```

to

```
public function addCartLink()
{
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
        $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
            : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            $text = $this->__('</span></span>%s</span></span>', $count);
        } elseif ($count > 0) {
            $text = $this->__('<span><span>%s</span></span>', $count);
        } else {
            $text = $this->__('<span><span>0'</span></span>);
        }
```

So, now the items number is showing inside/above the shopping cart image. Just as i wanted it to be. Problem is: By hoovering over the link it shows now the span span-tags before and after the item number.

Any idea how to change that link title there? Or maybe is there a even better way to display a shoppingcart image in the toplinks?

Comment: Can you simply do without the span tags, and adjust your CSS to not need them?  (Perhaps you should post your CSS.)

Comment: Also, is that second block of code what you're actually using?  Because it isn't valid PHP (misplaced quotation mark).

Comment: You are right, i did it now without the span tags and it worked. In the CSS i had used display:block instead of display:inline that caused me some trouble before.

By hoovering over the cart it shows now the item number, thats not perfect but OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little below the block you quoted in the Magento source, I see this line:

```
$parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
```

Try providing different values for the two values that $text is given for - I bet one of them is the HTML of the link, and the other is the tooltip text.  (You should probably use `$this->__()` for the new text as well, for consistency - though it's unlikely to have any effect, since what it does is allow Magento to translate that text to another language.)  You could then have spans in the HTML version, while leaving them out of the tooltip.